# How extract image from DOC file without using of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, doc

I'm trying to extract image from *.doc file without using of  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I found library like FreeSpire.Doc, but It seems the free version of library isn't able to extract images. Can someone help me with this problem?

[Attached *.doc file with the image I need][1]
[1]: https://mega.nz/#!5nITyQzT!aesEA0akirlpKSEEDceNDjifOAFKlNZSmgTwfhFm36M

Thank you

Comment: Are you bound to `.doc`-documents or can you use `.docx`?

Comment: Yes, my source document type is *.doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution. I found a library named GemBox.Document. Unluckily this library is free only for documents containing up to 20 paragraphs. So I had to remove extra paragraphs and then I used this code to get first picture in document.

```
        public void CreateSubnestImageFromNestingReport(string picturePath,string  docPath)
    {
        var fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(picturePath);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDir);

        ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
        var document = DocumentModel.Load(docPath, LoadOptions.DocDefault);
        var pict = document.GetChildElements(true).Single(el => el.ElementType == ElementType.Picture) as Picture;
        File.WriteAllBytes(picturePath, pict.PictureStream.ToArray());            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only library i found which can extract Images from .doc Document is [Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/products/words). There is an [example](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Working+with+Images#WorkingwithImages-HowtoExtractImagesfromaDocument) in their documentation how you can Export Images.

Comment: Shape namespace: Aspose.Words.Drawing has to added manually in VS